# Magento success and error message not persisting through redirect

Tags: magento

I have a controller which does some processing and then redirects using `redirectReferrer`.  For some reason error and success messages are being lost.  I am assuming this is because they are flushed after the first request?

Can anyone a: explain if this is the case and why.  b: explain how this can be overcome

Comment: Can you please post the code you're using right before `redirectReferrer`? Are you using a `return;` right after you call this function?

Comment: R u using Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session') class for errors ?